# maintain connection status of user with firestore. using firebase db and cloud function

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to maintain connection status of user with firestore . but i don't understand some points.

Link : https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/presence

i refer the above link description but i don't understand how to write code.
see the below given topics:

1. **Using presence in Realtime Database**

   where to write this given  code in application or Cloud functions?

2.Connecting to Cloud Firestore

1. **Updating Cloud Firestore's local cache**

   where to write local cache update code?

I use this in my android application.

Answer (score 0):

Each section of the code in the [Build Presence in Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/presence) is marked.

If it is marked with <kbd>WEB</kbd>, you'll need to run this code in your web application. If your clients are native Android or iOS, you'll need to write and run similar code for those platforms.

If the code is marked with <kbd>NODE.JS</kbd>, you will need to run this code in a Node.js environment. It should be possible to accomplish the same in Cloud Functions, but no sample is provided for that.